# Map activity in android

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity

I have created map actvity.But its not showing map on mapview.just showing blank blocks.
is there any solution?

activity_main.xml-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

activity code-

```
package com.example.googlemap;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

manifest file-

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyDRv4Ul_9iPW-roHIsc8EuxKwkRN8jWivs"
    android:value="AIzaSyDRv4Ul_9iPW-roHIsc8EuxKwkRN8jWivs" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

after using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)
i'm getting following exception-

```
  08-22 23:19:52.204: E/AndroidRuntime(584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-22 23:19:52.204: E/AndroidRuntime(584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemap/com.example.googlemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old MapView has been depreciated. You can't create a new Map key for publishing your app. 
You have to use new Google Maps for Android v2 API. Here's a link to the documents and example. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: i have used the same.using above code i'm getting following error msg on logcat- android mapactivity couldn't get connection factory client

Comment: Above code is from the old API which has been depreciated. I would suggest you use the new API v2.

Comment: Your code up above is still the same. There's no MapActivity and MapView in the new API. Take a look at the example how to use it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Answer (score 2):

> make sure **Google Repository** && **Google play Services** is up to Date

add below to Project level Gradle

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and below two statements to App Level Gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'//for location
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'//for maps
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.1'//for places
```

And add permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

add below statment in  tag

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_map_key" />
```

**MapsActivity.class**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private EditText searchPlaceEt;
    private Button saveLocationBtn;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);

        mContext = MapsActivity.this;

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();

                if(mMap != null)
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                ///checkLocationPermission();
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            if(mMap != null)
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                position(mMap.getCameraPosition().target).title("Near to Sydney"));

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.draggable(true);
                markerOptions.title("Add a hazard here.");
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                ///mHazardsMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                LatLng objLoc = marker.getPosition();
                return false;
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                LatLng objLoc = marker.getPosition();
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

**fragment_map**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".maptest.MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could do this with the Google Map Activity bundled with Android Studio 1.2.1.1.  I created a Google Maps Activity and followed the instructions as below:

1. Created the API Key following the instructions in google_maps_api.xml

   ```
   To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:
   ```

   *https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY%3Bnpackagename*

   ```
   You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
   XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY:XY;newmapscreen.avapps.nbapl.com.newmapscreen

   Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
   string in this file.
   -->
   <string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
       AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   </string>
   ```

After that, I ensured all the dependencies are there in Android Manifest, build.gradle. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813789/android-google-mapview-activity-not-opening-in-android-studio/30880045#30880045) for details.

In your MapActivity.java, you can add additional markers, and use the Android Google Maps API V2 features to enhance your map.

(replace XY:XY ...with whats in your google_maps_api.xml)